# Apply patch to library for custom changes in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, library, rtc, esp32

I wish to obtain unix epoch timestamps in millisecond precision. I am using an ESP32 along with **DS3231** RTC breakout board from adafruit.

Apparently the Repository is not maintained often but I see a [PR](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/pull/92) which overcomes the rollover for software timer and the developer provided a patch in the comment to use the unix timestamps in ms.

I went to the `libraries` folder where all the downloaded adafruit repos exist. But when I did  `git status` it mentions that the library download (from the library manager) is not a git repository.

I wan't to inculcate the changes to the `RTClib` library by using the patch provided. Should I just change the code directly via the Arduino IDE editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the patch to a file, put it in the directory holding the library,
open a terminal on that directory and type:

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

You may have to install the "patch" utility if you don't have it yet. On
a Debian-like OS (I don't know for other OSes):

```
sudo apt install patch
```

Comment: Well I blundered and cloned a fork from your repo and added the patch to it. Added this updated repo to the IDE. I think I will revert back to your method.